# Use conditional coloring on a plotly surface

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

I am using plotly via R for the first time and trying to create a surface from a grid and color it based on a calculation.

For example, I would like to use the surface from `data(volcano)`, as in

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

But instead of color based on the z-value (altitude), let's just say I wanted to color based on distance from my house on the little mesa at (20,60) .

```
house_loc <- c(20,60,150) # (x,y,z) of my house
dist_to_house <- Vectorize(function(x,y,z){sqrt(sum( (c(x,y,z)-house_loc)^2 ))})
```

So far I have tried:

```
color_me <-function(x){
  colorRampPalette(c('tan','blue')
  )(24L)[findInterval(x,seq(0,1,length.out=25),
                      all.inside=TRUE)]
} 

library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
volcano %>% 
     melt( varnames=c('y','x'),value.name='z' ) %>%
     mutate( d = dist_to_house(x, y, z) ,
             d_rel = d/max(d),
             d_color = color_me(d_rel) 
     ) -> df

plot_ly(df,
        type='scatter3d',
        mode='none', # no markers, just surface
        x=~x,
        y=~y,
        z=~z,
        surfaceaxis=2,
        surfacecolor=~d_color) # last argument seems not to work
```

Which just returns:

[image]

The desired result would color the landscape tan in the region of the house and gradually fade to blue in the regions far from the house.

Somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156281/mesh3d-how-to-colour-the-faces-of-the-triangles-r-plotly) uses `mesh3d` code found elsewhere and doesn't explain how to calculate (i, j, k)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code virtually has everything you need, just use a `surface` plot and use your distance array as the `color`.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

house_loc <- c(20,60,150)
dist_to_house <- Vectorize(function(x,y,z){sqrt(sum( (c(x,y,z)-house_loc)^2 ))})

volcano %>% 
  melt( varnames=c('y','x'),value.name='z' ) %>%
  mutate( d = dist_to_house(x, y, z) ,
          d_rel = d/max(d)
  ) -> df

color <- df$d_rel
dim(color) <- dim(volcano)

plot_ly(df,
        type='surface',
        z=volcano,
        surfacecolor=color,
        colors=c('tan','blue'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the colors! I added it to the answer.

Comment: hi there - i've been trying to do something similar, and this is the closest i've come to a solution, but it still doesn't work in my implementation. I'm trying to map a color matrix onto a 3D surface which is FLAT (i.e. a flat pane, essentially a 2d heatmap floating in a 3d plane). As soon as I use this code with a z matrix of all 1s with variable a color matrix as the surfacecolor, I get a unicolor surface.Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @renegademonkey: Please post it as a separate question together with your code and I am sure there is somebody who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `surface` plot (see accepted answer) we can also do a `mesh3d` plot and avoid the reshaping (back to grid) step that plot requires.

However, the scale bar still isn't right (showing range of `z`, not  `d_rel`)

```
plot_ly(df,
        type='mesh3d',
        x = ~x,
        y = ~y,
        z = ~z,
        intensity=~d_rel,
        colors = colorRamp(c("tan", "blue"))
    )
```

Counter-intuitively, it is `intensity=` and not `color=` which seems to control the conditional coloring.

[image]

I originally avoided `mesh3d` because I thought I had to create a triangular mesh (Delaunay something or another) and had no idea how to do that, but it seems to be handled automatically in this case.

Comment: If anybody knows how to fix the scale bar, please comment or answer.