# Use conditional coloring on a plotly surface python

Tags: python, graph, colors, 3d, plotly

Would someone be able to explain how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963243/use-conditional-coloring-on-a-plotly-surface) in Python instead of R? I have Plotly working and everything else, I just do not know how to get the colourmapping to match a fourth variable. Thanks everyone

Comment: Hi Andrew, you could check [this](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-coloring/). It seems to me that in this example the main problem is to transform the given data in `(x,y,z)` coordinates

Comment: Update it seems to me that rows are y coordinates, columns are x coordinates and on the intersection you have z values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the syntax given by [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-coloring/) did not work for me. However you can specify surfacecolor by adding it in the go.Surface such as

```
 trace1 = go.Surface( z=surface1, surfacecolor = color)
```

where both surface1 and color here are two-dimensional arrays storing the values you want in the corresponding x,y position.