# How plotly package in R creates solid 3D mesh from vertex information without face information

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, r-plotly

I have 3D vertex coordinates (vb.xlsx) and face information (it.xlsx) for human face available [here](https://github.com/Patricklv/Smoothing-3D-surface/tree/master). I managed to plot 3D surface mesh with rgl package by providing both vertex and face information (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918849/smooth-3d-trangular-mesh-in-r)). What surprised me is that with plotly package in R, I can get solid 3D surface mesh of human face only by providing vertex data, where face information is unnecessary. Below is my R code to generate the surface mesh:

```
library(plotly)
library(xlsx)

vb <- read.xlsx("E:\\Research\\GM\\3D started\\Spatially dense\\Point cloud to mesh\\vb.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = F)

Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="<MY USER NAME>")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="<MY KEY>")

face <- plot_ly(
    x = vb[,1], y = vb[,2], z = vb[,3], # Note only vertex provided
    type = "mesh3d"
)

face
```

The resultant surface mesh is as follows:
[image]

My question is how does plotly managed to generate 3D surface mesh without face information? Can anyone show me the magic code under the hood so that I could do the same thing outside plotly with some self-written code?

Thank you.

Comment: This is documented on the plotly help page https://plot.ly/r/reference/#mesh3d:  it can do Delaunay triangulation (like `rgl::persp3d.deldir`) or the "alpha-shape" algorithm (which isn't supported by `rgl`).

Comment: The `alphashape3d` package does the "alpha-shape" algorithm, and has a `plot` method using `rgl`.

Comment: If anyone's desperately trying to figure out how to add faces to plotly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39175718/11738400